# Why does this fail Q

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I am running an SQL statement with this to create a field and I get the desired result:

```
TO_CHAR(TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE - 8/24,'hh24'), 'DD-Mon-yyyy hh24:mi') AS "DATEVAR"
```

When I add this to my where statement in the SQL, I get results with the correct time period but not in the MMDDYY scope.  What gives?

```
WHERE
TO_CHAR(MOPACTIVITY.MOPEND, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:') < TO_CHAR(TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE - 8/24,'hh24'), 'DD-Mon-yyyy hh24:mi')
```

You genius is greatly appreciated.

Respectfully,

Jonathan Morningstar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing `dd-mon-yyyy` using "<".  Of course the range is off.  If you want to compare these as strings, then use `yyyy-mm-dd`:

```
WHERE TO_CHAR(MOPACTIVITY.MOPEND, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:') < TO_CHAR(TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE - 8/24,'hh24'), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi')
```

Wouldn't it be easier to compare these as dates?

```
where MOPACTIVITY < TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE - 8/24)
```

Answer (score 2):

to_char returns strings, so you are comparing strings, not date. So they are compared alphabetically.